# D3: Create a continuous color scale with many strings/inputs for the range and dynamically changing values of the domain

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a linear color scale for a heatmap. I want to color scale to go through a large set of specific colors, where the first color corresponds to the min of the data and the last color should be given to the max of the data.

I know that I can do this by also giving the domain 17 values in between the min and max, but I do not know how to do this dynamically if the user is able to change the dataset (and thus change the coloring of the heatmap)

In essence I would like to following, but I know it does not work

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
   .range(["#6363FF", "#6373FF", "#63A3FF", "#63E3FF", "#63FFFB", "#63FFCB",
           "#63FF9B", "#63FF6B", "#7BFF63", "#BBFF63", "#DBFF63", "#FBFF63", 
           "#FFD363", "#FFB363", "#FF8363", "#FF7363", "#FF6364"])
   .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) {return d;}),
            d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d;})]);
```

Can anybody please tell me what I need to put into 'domain' to make it work?

EDIT:
I did find something that does what I want. Using R I calculated 256 colors in between the 17 from above with the designer.colors functions and put this into the range. This does give the feeling of a continous color scale

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range(["#6363FF", "#6364FF", "#6364FF", "#6365FF",
            "... several other lines with color codes ..."
            "#FF6764", "#FF6564", "#FF6464", "#FF6364"])
    .domain(d3.range(1,257));

var quantize = d3.scale.quantile()
   .range(d3.range(1,257))
   .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) {return d;}), 
            d3.max(dataset, function(d) {return d;})]);
```

Now I can use the color in this fashion

```
colorScale(quantize(dataset))
```

But I'm wondering if this can also be done in less lines of code?

Comment: Just seen your edit, it's essentially the same as my answer.  I would map to 0-1 so it's completely general.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You want to split the problem up.  First define a scale for your heatmap that maps 0-1 to your colours.  Then define a second (dynamic) scale that maps your dataset to 0-1.  You can then combine the scales to paint your shapes.

```
var colours = ["#6363FF", "#6373FF", "#63A3FF", "#63E3FF", "#63FFFB", "#63FFCB",
               "#63FF9B", "#63FF6B", "#7BFF63", "#BBFF63", "#DBFF63", "#FBFF63", 
               "#FFD363", "#FFB363", "#FF8363", "#FF7363", "#FF6364"];

var heatmapColour = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.range(0, 1, 1.0 / (colours.length - 1)))
  .range(colours);

// dynamic bit...
var c = d3.scale.linear().domain(d3.extent(dataset)).range([0,1]);

// use the heatmap to fill in a canvas or whatever you want to do...
canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  // snip...
  .style("fill", function(d) {
     return heatmapColour(c(d));
```

Plus you can use the d3.extent function to get the min and max of the dataset in one go.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! Your version truly interpolates the colors for all possible values in the range, whereas mine was setting it to one of the 256 colors

Comment: Just to say a thanks from me too, your solution is absolutely perfect for a similar problem to mine.

Comment: Hi - thank you this seems pretty useful. What is the `canvas` variable? I'm new to D3 and I can see that working with a `canvas` HTML element, while I do have a `.append` I don't have a `.data`.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [Quantitative Scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#quantize) plus [Color Brewer](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/tree/master/lib/colorbrewer)

```
// pick any number [3-9]
var numColors = 9;

var heatmapColour = d3.scale.quantize()
  .domain(d3.extent(dataset))
  .range(colorbrewer.Reds[numColors]);

// use the heatmap to fill in a canvas or whatever you want to do...
canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  // snip...
  .style("fill", function(d) {return heatmapColour(d);})
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [threshold scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-threshold-scales). Here is a quick example:

```
coffee> d3 = require 'd3'
coffee> color = d3.scale.threshold().domain([5,30,100]).range(["red","orange","green"]);
coffee> color 6
'orange'
coffee> color 3
'red'
coffee> color 33
'green'
```