# D3 scales for maps

Tags: d3.js

I am  a d3 newbie though I understand range and domain quite.
I have a confusion regarding D3 scale specially in relation to choropleth.
Which is best scale to use in case of choropleths.

Comment: What type of data are you using?

Comment: If you're trying to convert a continuous numerical data scale into a fixed set of colour values, you probably want either a *quantize* or a *threshold* scale.  [This Q&A has more information on the scales](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21787200/3128209).